# Javascript - is the keydown is the numpad decimal separator

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I have a "simple" problem but can't find a solution to it.

**My problem:** I want to know if the keydown is the decimal separator key on the numpad (not depending if it's a en/fr/de keyboard).

**The easy answer:** use keyCode = 110, but keyCode is deprecated and I would like a sustainable solution.

**The .key solution:** I try the Keyboardevent.key and IE/Edge always return "Decimal" (great!!), but when I try it on Chrome it doesn't works, and return "." or "," and the charCode of the char is the same as the "." or "," key.

I take a look on similar post on stackoverflow, but the questions are more about "what is the local decimal separator" than "is the key is the numpad decimal separator".

Is anyone encountered the same problem and found a solution?
My last choice is to use the keyCode, but I would like to avoid this solution.

Comment: Use [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) where applicable, and provide a fallback by `keyCode`.

Comment: @Teemu Works great on Chrome. Doesn't work on IE, but by cumulating key and code and it should do the job. I hope it will works too on Opera/FF. Thank a lot for your solution

Comment: `code` works in FF, you can see the Browser compatibility table at the end of the MDN page.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the one @Teemu gave.

I use this function to retrieve if it's the DecimalSeparator that had been pressed.

```
function isKeyDS(evt) {
    if (evt.key !== undefined && evt.key === "Decimal") { // IE / Edge
        return true;
    }
    if (evt.code !== undefined && evt.code == "NumpadDecimal") { // Chrome / FF / Opera
        return true;
    }

    return evt.keyCode === 110; // Compatibiliy with old browser
}
```